# How to set health check to run only on url call

Tags: c#, health-monitoring

I managed to implement MS health check from this site:   [Health checks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

But it calls health checks in every 10 seconds. What I need is to run health check on calling the /health uri only. Kubernetes will call this endpoint and determine health status by the status code returns.

How to do this?

Comment: Section basic health check in link that you share https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#basic-health-probe

Comment: Yes, calling the /health endpoint works great. The main problem is that the checks run inevery 10 seconds which shouldn't.

Comment: This is a problem in your kubernetes deployment, post your code k8s deployment

Comment: Kubernetes is only an example what will call /health endpoint. The problem is independent from Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm grappling with this same issue at the moment. It's not kubernetes specific, as I see my healthcheck being invoked even running my app locally. I thought it was related to the HealthCheckPublisherHostedService trying to publish healthchecks periodically, but I've tried the workaround described in this post and I'm still seeing the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29896